# How to put radio buttons within list

Tags: javascript, html, mean-stack

I'm trying to put a radio button on each of my list elements as you can see here.

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="player in vm.players">
        {{player.name}}
      <span class="pull-right">
        <input type="radio" name="gender"value="player.name">
      </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I hope basically to show a list of player's name and you can select some with a radio button, but they don't seem to allow you to click them.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the missing space between the name and value attributes relevant?

Comment: unfortunately not.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "don't allow you to click them" - I ran the snippet and the radio button can be clicked just fine. Do you by any chance refer to the player name? If so, wrap the player name and the input in a `<label>` element.

Comment: Interestingly it does allow you to click them on the snippet, so it must be a css issue on my end, will investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dimodi suggests, if you want text to be associated with a clickable form input like a checkbox or radio button, you must associate them using a `<label>`. For example, either of:

```
<label><input...> some text</label>

<input id="foo"...> <label for="foo">some text</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind label for attribute with radio's id.
   Or 
Simply placed radio inside particular label.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="player in vm.players">
    <label>  {{player.name}}
      <input type="radio" name="gender"value="player.name">
      </label>

      <label for="plys">  {{player.name}}  </label>
        <input type="radio" id="plys" name="gender"value="player.name">

    </li>
 </ul>
```